# Error: Could not locate the bindings file [Ubuntu-19-04, nodejs and npm]

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, visual-studio-code, raspberry-pi

I am building a project on `visual studio code`. I have successfully installed `node.js` version `12.13` and `npm` version `6.12` on my `Ubuntu-19.04`. Part of the code will also be execute on a `raspberry-pi` as external device.
The project seems to run but at a certain point during the compilation and right after launching `npm start` it throws an error

`Error: Could not locate the bindings file.Tried:` and there is a small list. The print screen is attached below and I am not sure how to take care of that:

[image: error]

I am very close to make it work and have been trying to research the potential error but could not find any useful information. 
Please point to the right direction for solving this issue.